# passing value to previous viewController , delegate method is not being called

Tags: swift

i am getting the value of schoolAddress from a function. i pass the value of schoolAddress after the view disappears. m trying to pass the value of school address from GeoDetailsVC to EditChildPoofileVC..
thanx in advance

```
protocol DataEnteredDelegate : class {
    func setLocations(info: String)
}

class GeoDetailsVC: UIViewController{
    weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = nil
    var schoolAddress: String = ""

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        self.delegate?.setLocations(self.schoolAddress)
        print(schoolAddress)
    }
}

class EditChildProfileVC: UIViewController, DataEnteredDelegate  {

    var locationSentFromGeoDetailsVC:String?
    @IBOutlet weak var schoolAddressTF: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("EditChildProfileVC")
        self.title = ChildName
    }

    func setLocations(info: String) {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            self.locationSentFromGeoDetailsVC = info
            self.schoolAddressTF.text = self.locationSentFromGeoDetailsVC
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue == "GeoDetailsSegue" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! GeoDetailsVC
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this line `vc.delegate = self` actually being called? Why are you comparing segue with a string? It should be `segue.identifier`

Comment: Just pass the data from prepareForSegue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `segue == "GeoDetailsSegue"` to `segue.identifier == "GeoDetailsSegue"`, like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let segueIdentifier = segue.identifier else { return }
    if segueIdentifier == "GeoDetailsSegue",
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? GeoDetailsVC {
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```